Does the construction of the dataframe change the values of the list?
If I write this:
f <- function(lambda, a_0, n) {
  a <- numeric(n)
  a[1] <- a_0
  for (i in 2:n) {
    a[i] <- lambda * a[i-1] * (1 - a[i-1])
  }
  return(a)
}
f(4, 0.75, 100)

then a list is produced that contains only the number 0.75. This is expected.
However, if I write:
lambda <- 4
n <- 100
a_0_values <- seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.05)
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(a_0_values), nrow = n))
for (i in 1:length(a_0_values)) {
  df[, i] <- f(lambda, a_0_values[i], n)
}
df[,15]

then a list is produced that initially contains 0.75, but after a while, it starts changing (see the table I provide at the end).
I tried increasing the length of the generated list by writing up to f(4, 0.75, 1000000), and it still worked as expected. It only produced 0.75, as it should. Of course, even if it did change after a certain point, it still doesn't explain why f(4, 0.75, 100) and df[,15] produce different results.
Why is that?
df[,15]
  [1] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
  [7] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
 [13] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
 [19] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
 [25] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.499999e-01
 [31] 7.500001e-01 7.499998e-01 7.500005e-01 7.499990e-01 7.500019e-01 7.499962e-01
 [37] 7.500076e-01 7.499847e-01 7.500305e-01 7.499390e-01 7.501221e-01 7.497558e-01
 [43] 7.504881e-01 7.490228e-01 7.519506e-01 7.460836e-01 7.577714e-01 7.342156e-01
 [49] 7.805721e-01 6.851171e-01 8.629266e-01 4.731372e-01 9.971136e-01 1.151244e-02
 [55] 4.551962e-02 1.737903e-01 5.743490e-01 9.778889e-01 8.648884e-02 3.160341e-01
 [61] 8.646262e-01 4.681910e-01 9.959528e-01 1.612345e-02 6.345395e-02 2.377102e-01
 [67] 7.248162e-01 7.978306e-01 6.451876e-01 9.156822e-01 3.088332e-01 8.538210e-01
 [73] 4.992429e-01 9.999977e-01 9.170494e-06 3.668164e-05 1.467212e-04 5.867986e-04
 [79] 2.345817e-03 9.361256e-03 3.709449e-02 1.428740e-01 4.898440e-01 9.995874e-01
 [85] 1.649634e-03 6.587650e-03 2.617701e-02 1.019671e-01 3.662792e-01 9.284750e-01
 [91] 2.656366e-01 7.802952e-01 6.857385e-01 8.620049e-01 4.758098e-01 9.976593e-01
 [97] 9.340721e-03 3.701389e-02 1.425754e-01 4.889907e-01


At a guess, perhaps this.

@Limey , does this explain why f(4, 0.75, 100) produces a different result than df[,15]?

As @ThomasIsCoding explains in their answer, yes - I believe it does.

@Limey Now I understand... Thanks again for the answer!

I think it might be the precision of a_0 value, since you can see that
> a_0_values[15] - 0.75
[1] 1.110223e-16



If you apply a_0_values[15] to f

> f(lambda, a_0_values[15], n)
  [1] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
  [6] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
 [11] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
 [16] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
 [21] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01
 [26] 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.500000e-01 7.499999e-01
 [31] 7.500001e-01 7.499998e-01 7.500005e-01 7.499990e-01 7.500019e-01
 [36] 7.499962e-01 7.500076e-01 7.499847e-01 7.500305e-01 7.499390e-01
 [41] 7.501221e-01 7.497558e-01 7.504881e-01 7.490228e-01 7.519506e-01
 [46] 7.460836e-01 7.577714e-01 7.342156e-01 7.805721e-01 6.851171e-01
 [51] 8.629266e-01 4.731372e-01 9.971136e-01 1.151244e-02 4.551962e-02
 [56] 1.737903e-01 5.743490e-01 9.778889e-01 8.648884e-02 3.160341e-01
 [61] 8.646262e-01 4.681910e-01 9.959528e-01 1.612345e-02 6.345395e-02
 [66] 2.377102e-01 7.248162e-01 7.978306e-01 6.451876e-01 9.156822e-01
 [71] 3.088332e-01 8.538210e-01 4.992429e-01 9.999977e-01 9.170494e-06
 [76] 3.668164e-05 1.467212e-04 5.867986e-04 2.345817e-03 9.361256e-03
 [81] 3.709449e-02 1.428740e-01 4.898440e-01 9.995874e-01 1.649634e-03
 [86] 6.587650e-03 2.617701e-02 1.019671e-01 3.662792e-01 9.284750e-01
 [91] 2.656366e-01 7.802952e-01 6.857385e-01 8.620049e-01 4.758098e-01
 [96] 9.976593e-01 9.340721e-03 3.701389e-02 1.425754e-01 4.889907e-01


If you round it by 2 digits

> f(lambda, round(a_0_values[15], 2), n)
  [1] 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 [16] 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 [31] 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 [46] 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 [61] 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 [76] 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 [91] 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75


Oh! I didn't expect that! I didn't expect seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.05) to give the 15th term as 0.75+1.110223e-16. Isn't that strange? Thanks a lot for the answer!

@KώσταςΚούδας i think that is a fact of R, we should be aware of the float numbers when applying seq, especially when your function heavily relies on the steady point (your function is kind of "fixed-point" process)

I see. I know the sequence I generated. I know it has fixed points, which is why I was surprised not to encounter a column full of 0.75. Thank you very much for the answers!
